# java mathematical function f(x)

Tags: java, function, math

I'm trying to make a mathematical function: f(x) = x - 3 / (x * x) - 4. It has the user input a value for x (x is "a") but I don't know how to get it use x in the function.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double z = f(1);
    System.out.println("Answer: " + z);
}

public static double f(double x) {
    double y = 0;
    String a = "";
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter value for 'x': ");
    a = reader.nextLine();
    y = a - 3 / (a * a) - 4);
    return y;
}
```

Comment: you probably want `reader.nextDouble()` not reader.nextLine()

Comment: and just simply make a local variable `double a = 0;`. Also get rid of the parameter you send it... that has no point in this method

Comment: And you should have the same number of `)` as you have `(` in an expression.

Comment: 'x is "a"' Why not make x "x"? Why make it more confusing than it needs to be?

Answer (score 6):

What you are looking for to take the user's input is `nextDouble()`, rather than `nextLine` which returns a `String` and not a `double`. Also, it would make more sense to handle the user's input outside the `function`, and pass the input as an argument. So it would look something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double a;
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter value for 'x': ");
    a = reader.nextDouble();
    double z = f(a);
    System.out.println("Answer: " + z);
}

public static double f(double x) {
    return x - 3 / (x * x) - 4;
}
```

Comment: very nice you could just have `return (x - 3 / (x * x) - 4);`.